# Value Object optimization using array functions of PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two methods inside a Value Object:

```
public final function unlockableLetters()
{
    return [
        [],
        ['A', 'B'],
        ['C']
    ][$this->level];
}

public final function unlockedLetters()
{
    return [
        [],
        ['A', 'B'],
        ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ][$this->level];
}
```

The first one returns unlockable elements of each level.

- At level 0, returns [].
- At level 1 returns A and B.
- At level 2 returns C.

The second one returns unlocked elements.

- At level 0, returns [].
- At level 1 returns A and B.      // NULL + A + B
- At level 2 returns A, B and C.   // A + B + C

There is a way to use array functions of php that create an merge of array returned by unlockLetters() from index 0 to current $this->level?

**EDIT**
I want to leave letters only inside **unlockableLetters()** method. So, **unlockedLetters()** can "build" its own return value from first method. If something change in the former, change will occur in the latter.

Comment: You've spent a lot of time setting up your question, but your actual question is a bit terse and hard to understand. I for one am very unclear on what it is that you're asking.

Comment: I agree with @deceze, its not clear what you want to merge... are you saying you wantto generate the return of `unlockedLetters()` from `unlockLetters()` using array functions instead of hard coding it? Also i think better method names are in order here because that also makes it confusing... i would use `getUnlockableLetters` and `getUnlockedLetters()` or something along those lines depending on how these are used.

Comment: I've edited unlockedLetters() to unlockableLetters(). Is more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you want. As I said in my comment:

> agree with @deceze, it's not clear what you want to merge... are you saying you want to generate the return of `unlockedLetters()` from `unlockLetters()` using array functions instead of hard coding it? Also I think better method names are in order here because that also makes it confusing... I would use `getUnlockableLetters` and `getUnlockedLetters()` or something along those lines depending on how these are used.

However, what I think you mean might look something like this:

```
// add a property so we can reference it - you might want to adjust
// the visibility to private or public depending on its nature
protected $unlockableLetters = [
    [],
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['C']
];

public final function unlockLetters()
{
    // just return the reference to the letters for the level
    return $this->unlockableLetters[$this->level];
}

public final function unlockedLetters()
{
    // slice off the array of latters from the lowest level 
    // to the current one - note the +1 since array_slice
    // wants a length and our offsets are 0-based and thus length-1
    $data = array_slice($this->unlockableLetters, 0, $this->level+1);

    // use array reduce to build a single array that has
    // all the letters for levels 0 --> $this->level
    return array_reduce($data, function ($merged, $datum) {
       return array_merge($merged, $datum);
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as I understand your question, you are looking for this

```
public final function unlockableLetters() {
    $unlockables = [
        [],
        ['A', 'B'],
        ['C']
    ];
    return array_reduce(array_slice($unlockables, 0, $this->level + 1), function($carry, $item){
        return array_merge($carry, $item);
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other developers here. 
Question is not clear.
But here is my guess:

```
public final function unlockLetters()
{
    $arr =  [
        [],
        ['A', 'B'],
        ['C']
        ];
    return $arr[$this->level];
}

public final function unlockedLetters()
{
    $arr = [
        [],
        ['A', 'B'],
        ['A', 'B', 'C']
    ];
    return $arr[$this->level];
}
```

Comment: Ok, sorry. I've updated the question. The point is I do not want to change both method if something change. I want to leave $arr only inside unlockableLetters().